# writing an sql statement inside an asp control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql

How should i write an sql statement in an SqlDataSource control?

```
<% String inuser="john";%>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
                   runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="..." 
                   SelectCommand="select from users where user='<%#inuser%>'??????????????" DeleteCommand="..." InsertCommand="..." 
                   UpdateCommand="...">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd be better served setting the value in the code-behind's load event handler:

```
var inuser = "john";
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select from users where user = @user";
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@user", inuser);
```

You can also do it through the markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
                   runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="..." 
                   SelectCommand="select from users where user=@user">
    <selectparameters>
        <asp:Parameter name="user" DefaultValue="john"/>
    </selectparameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```